# Can i still use my windows 8 programs such as autocad, photoshop, sketch up with ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit

Im not a computer geek, but i wish someone will help me to install the latest ubuntu os to my lenovo laptop with windows 8 pre installed. If i removed windows 8 as my os can i still use my other programs such as autocad, photoshop, sketch up with ubuntu?

Comment: In general No Ubuntu does is not Windows so won't natively run Windows software just as Windows won't run Mac software or Ubuntu software.  There is a compatibility layer called Wine which will allow some Windows software to run but it doesn't work well with everything.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to use those programs.

This is because Ubuntu is an entirely separate operating system and the applications have to be installed within said OS. 
(Note: OS=Operating System)

While those programs may have linux compatibilty, you'd have to install them within Ubuntu.

However, may I ask what is your reasoning for installing Ubuntu?  There may not be a need to replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu, and installing Ubuntu on a pre-configured laptop can have adverse effects on the system (As I have encountered).

I suggest either installing Ubuntu side-by-side with your windows installation, which is referred to as dual booting. (Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

If you really want to remove the Windows 8 OS and replace it with Linux, I suggest formatting your hard drive first to wipe the Windows installation (Refer to http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/format-hard-drive-windows-7.htm)

Then install the latest LTS version of Ubuntu which is currently 14.04 LTS (Refer to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

Now all you need is to burn that image onto a disc. And follow these steps from the Ubuntu i stallation documentation (refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

Make sure you have a good internet connection available whilst installing, and keep your Ubuntu as up-to-date as possible.

Comment: Adam, Your right I will try to install ubuntu side by side with windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called WINE (Wine Is Not Emulator) that you can use to run native windows applications. The project home is [Winehq.org](http://winehq.org). There you can search their database for applications that you can run through Wine. The program is included in the repositories so you can easily install it through software center.

Here are the links for [AutoCAD](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=103) which is gold status (i.e. no problems reported) and [Adobe Photoshop](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17).

Answer (score 0):

Autocad and photoshop you will cant use. This programms works only on windows. You may try Gimp - photoshop alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try installing ubuntu on a separate partition on your laptop ......

try this link for detailed step by step

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **VirtualBox** to run an Windows visualissed, then you can run most Windows applications within.

[image: Install via the software center]

You will need an installable copy for Windows to do this.

Another option is to use **Wine** to run Windows applications in Ubuntu directly.

[image: Install via the software center]

Note that application support is limited with Wine - you can search the website http://appdb.winehq.org/ for compatibility and installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wine (Windows Emulator) for installing these softwares but it may not work for all windows softwares. To download wine use

> > > > sudo apt-get install wine

Answer (score 0):

Also look at some of the open source alternatives:

Sketch-up is a web based application - it's no problem.

Photoshop is similar in functionality to Gimp, and Inkscape does a lot of what Illustrator does

AutoCad can be replaced with a variety of programs, which are mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering